# Laravel webpack npm run watch only works once

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

When run "npm run watch-poll" in Laravel 5.8 project with webpack, it work by only once, not stay and watch files to rebuild them again.

Test it in any console but nothing change

Comment: do you close the shell after running the command?

Comment: Of course not, watch work like "npm run development"

Comment: Which IDE do you use? I recall seeing a bug somewhere where the there was no console output but the files were actually been built.

Comment: I use phpstorm, i test "npm run watch-poll" in ide terminal and in windows console but the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution, completely deleted the node_modules folder, change laravel-mix version to "^4.0.7" in package.json, run npm install

Answer (score 0):

I blocked on that for hours. Solution :
in webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I just had the A of App to turn to a maj :

```
mix.js('resources/js/App.js', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

And here we go...